# Calculating percentile of moving matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, percentile

I am dealing with financial ratios and I would like to construct a data frame consisting of the percentual order of an observation relative to a moving matrix.

Suppose that I have the following data frame

```
AAPL <- c(5,7,15,6,9,15,12,10,5,8)
MSFT <- c(20,14,12,15,10,15,18,22,17,20)
df <- data.frame (AAPL, MSFT)
```

What I would like to do is to create a new data frame consisting of the percentual order of a given observation based on the last 4 observations and the observation itself.

For this simplified exercise, I have run it in Excel and the new data frame would be:

```
AAPL.new <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0.75,0.75,0.5,0.5,0,0.25)
MSFT.new <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0.75,1,1,0.5,0.75)
df.new <- c(AAPL.new, MSFT.new)
```

I am a begginer, trying to move from working with small samples in Excel to larger samples in R. In Excel the function for this exercise would be percentrank.

What is the equivalent function in R? I have tried `quantile()` but I don't know how to make it give me a percentual order of a moving matrix.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a helper function `prank` for this job:

```
prank <- function(x, n){
    sapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
        if(i > n) sum(x[i] > x[(i-n):(i-1)]) / n
        else NA
    })
}

df.new <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, prank, n = 4))
# > df.new
#    AAPL MSFT
# 1    NA   NA
# 2    NA   NA
# 3    NA   NA
# 4    NA   NA
# 5  0.75 0.00
# 6  0.75 0.75
# 7  0.50 1.00
# 8  0.50 1.00
# 9  0.00 0.50
# 10 0.25 0.75
```